# Gulp watch is not working and I dont know why?

Tags: javascript, css, visual-studio, sass, gulp

When I want to use gulp watch in the VS Code in Terminal it is not working. It is a tricky for me.

I have code like:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var gulpSass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('buildcss', function(){
    return gulp.src('./dev-assets/style.scss')
    .pipe(gulpSass())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('./prod-assets'));
});

gulp.task('watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./dev-assets/**/*.scss', ['buildcss']);
});
```

It gives me the information: "Error: watching ./dev-assets/**/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated
by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)"

Please help :)

Comment: Could you please tell us which version of gulp are you using?

Comment: Of course, 
gulp": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.0.2"

Comment: Replace `['buildcss']` with `gulp.series('buildcss')` in your watch task.

Comment: Thank you my friend, it has worked! I am going to buy you a beer :)